# Time Complexity Analysis of Recursive Implementation of Generating Parenthesis

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

When we have a recursive function to generate parentheses with `N` valid parentheses, the time complexity is that of the Catalan number. This doesn't make sense to me.

My analysis of the time complexity is that, we have two operations at every node of the recursion tree. We can either add a close bracket or an opening bracket. So we make two recursive calls.

```
T(n) = 2 * T(N - 1) = O(2^N)
```

I get `O(2^N)` as my time complexity -- not the Catalan number. The Catalan number is so arbitrary to me -- it doesn't make sense. Could anyone explain it a bit further?

Answer (score 3):

In your assumption, you explore all cases that can be formed by the characters `'('` and `')'`. However, it is possible to eliminate some of those cases, isn't it? For instance, we know that for an input `N = 4`, `"))(("` is not a valid/balanced string. In fact, we know this to be true from the moment we put the first character of that string. Here's a recursive implementation in Python, just so that we can observe it through an example.

```
def generate(index, N, s, depth):
    if index == N:
        print s

    if depth > 0:
        generate(index + 1, N, s + ')', depth - 1)
    if depth < N:
        generate(index + 1, N, s + '(', depth + 1)
```

Essentially, in a recursive implementation, you keep a score of the current depth. Whenever that score is less than `0`, you know that your string becomes unbalanced, thus there is no point in exploring further. So, contrary to what you assumed, you do not explore **both** the subproblems.

If you think about it, the problem is simply finding the number of valid permutations of `N = 2 * K` different characters. At the first(leftmost) position, you can place `K` characters. (i.e. all the `'('`) In the second position, you can either place one of the `')'` characters, or you can place one of the remaining `K-1` `'('` characters. With this approach, using permutation with repetition, you can find that the complexity of the problem you mentioned is, indeed, equivalent to the K<sup>th</sup> Catalan number.

Basically, for a string of length `2N`, you have two different characters of which you have `N`, each. Using [permutation with repetition](https://brilliant.org/wiki/permutations-with-repetition/#permutations-with-repetition), **all** the possible permutations for this string would be `(2N)! / (N! N!)`. Well, the formula for the N<sup>th</sup> Catalan number is just that value, divided by an additional `(N+1)`, as you can see in the [relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number()). If you consider the cases where you do not handle the unbalanced strings I mentioned above, you can see that `(N+1)` factor is due to the cases where you don't compute both the subproblems.

Comment: Hm, it still doesn't click with me. I like the valid permutations analogy. But I can't go from there to the Catalan number -- it just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @asndonsadoasndo231213 I added a final paragraph to demonstrate how permutation with repetition gives you a number of permutations that are almost identical to the N<sup>th</sup> Catalan number. Perhaps that may help you go a little further in understanding the bound.